# Cannot get the variable in ng-model in directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive for comment input as follows, I want to reset the form after the user posted the comment. However, I can not get the `newComment` value of ng-model in `link` function. How to solve such problem.

**commenting.html**

```
<div class="directive__commenting">
  <div class="col-content">
    <h4>{{title}}({{count}})</h4>
    <form class="form" name="commentForm" ng-submit="createComment(commentForm, newComment)" ng-if="isLoggedIn()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="newComment" rows="3" placeholder="你怎么看？" ng-model="newComment" required></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="right">
        <span id="count-words" ng-class="{'red': isWordsExceeded(newComment)}">{{140 - newComment.length}}</span>
        <button class="send-button btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-disabled="isWordsExceeded()">{{btnActionTitle}}</button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</div> <!-- #create-comment -->
```

---

**commenting.directive.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myapp')
  .directive('commenting', function (Auth) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'components/directive/commenting/commenting.html',
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        title: '=',
        count: '=',
        btnActionTitle: '=',
        action: '='
      },
      link: function (scope) { //, element, attrs
        scope.isLoggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn;

        scope.isWordsExceeded = function (newComment) {
          return newComment && newComment.length > 140;
        }; //- isWordsExceeded

        scope.createComment = function (form, newComment) {
          scope.action(form, newComment)
          .then(function () { //success
            // clear the form, however here scope.newComment is undefined
          })
          .catch(function () { //fail 
          });
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

The directive is added in a html file as follows.

```
<div class="row" id="create-comment">
  <commenting title="'Comments'" count="model.comments.length" btn-action-title="'Submit comment'" action="createComment"></commenting>
</div> <!-- #create-comment -->
```

Comment: where did you include the directive in your HTML? there is no element nor attribute called "commenting" in it.

Comment: @morels I have updated the post. The directive is inserted in a html file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access through `scope` like

```
scope.newComment
```

Comment: I have mentioned that 'however here scope.newComment is undefined' in the code. I don't know why.

Comment: `// clear the form, however here scope.newComment is undefined` how do you clear the form ?